# Is it possible to have multiple sections in UItableView i.e: Section 1 has two sections and these two sections have multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Title says it all. I want to display an array of arrays and each index of array 2 has multiple arrays of rows

This is how it would look like if you like visual stuff

```
Section 1:
   Section 1
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
   Section 2
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
Section 2
    Section 1
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
   Section 2
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
Section 3
    Section 1
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
   Section 2
       Section 1
           Cell
       Section 2
           Cell
```

Comment: IDTS its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView has no built in support for this but you could create something yourself with some custom headers and cells.

basically create a model to support the structure:

```
let model = [[[a, b],[c,d]],[[e,f],[g,h]]]
```

your `numberOfSections` implementation would return `model.map{$0.count}.reduce(0, +)`

your `numberOfRowInSection` would do something like

```
let subSections = model[section]
var topLevelRow = indexPath.row
for subSection in subSections {
    if topLevelRow < subSection.count {
        print(subSection[topLevelRow])
        break
    } else {
        topLevelRow -= subSection.count
    }
}
```

the same implementation can be used for the `createCellAtIndexPath`

Last part would be to supply one header for when the section is the top section (subSection[0]) and another for if it's not.

There is a good example of multi level tableview in this article for how to go about it:
http://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so its easily possible because we define the number of Section table can have using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {` method.

We do not have in-built method to define number of section for the section.